# Angular2 RC6 Custom RequestOption Behaviour When CORS Post Request

Tags: http, angular, cors

I am currently writing something with Angular2 RC6 that extends the RequestOptions class that I want to be injected with some values that I need for customising the headers and request URL etc. This is working fine with GET requests but when I come to do a POST request I am experiencing some unexpected behaviour. The api I am calling is on a different domain so CORS browser policy is kicking in and issuing a pre-flight OPTIONS request which is expected but the RequestOptions code is kicking in twice but does not behave consistently.

There is some console log code to spit out the request method and the injected config object (all of which which is invoked twice for the post request with options):

```
Called testPost
Method: null (presume this is the options request but method is null)
RequestOptions Config: {"someKey":"someValue","anotherKey":"anotherValue"}
Method: 1 (is the post enum value of RequestMethod)
RequestOptions Config: undefined (no injected object for the actual post request)
```

I have created an PLUNKR example to illustrate (the POST request works in this example because it's not reliant on the injected config object but my actual implementation is so fails).

[PLUNKR Example](http://plnkr.co/Bcr0RfJIf65TXOkgwgs2)

Just wanted to check whether I am doing something wrong or if not whether should it be raised as an issue for RC6 on GitHub.

Comment: It's hard to debug in Plunker what's going on but it's hard to imagine that it's related to CORS. The OPTIONS request is a browser-only thing. Angular has no way to even know it happened except when it failed because the server didn't provide the required response headers.

Comment: OK but the fact remains I have issued a post request (different domains tested) and the request options code kicks in twice rather than just once so must be be an angular issue, I was supposing it was something to do with cors as I have two requests in the browser network Tab?

Comment: I guess there is some issue but I don't know details about `RequestOptions`. I just tried to point out that it's unlikely that this is related to the OPTIONS request.

Comment: Thanks. My main issue is that dependency injection is not working the second time when the post request is actually actioned, which in my actual implementation is key as the config holds api url and auth details and therefore the post request fails.

Comment: Somehow the merge method of your `CustomRequestOptions` class is applied to a plain `RequestOptions`. Try `console.log(this)` in `merge()`.

Comment: When the CustomRequestOptions class is called the second time when doing a POST request the RequestObject is passed through as: {"method":null,"headers":null,"body":{"title":"foo","body":"bar","userId":1},"url":null,"search":null,"withCredentials":null,"responseType":null} which has the object for the post in the body as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122842/discussion-between-monkeeman69-and-gunter-zochbauer).